# how to scrape data from telemart using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import bs4
import requests
url = requests.get(
    'https://www.telemart.pk/mobile-and-tablets/mobile-phone.html')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text, features='lxml')
print(soup)
```

i want to **scrape** price, image_link, product_link, title of each item but the data is in XHR . so how can i **scrape** data from xhr

Comment: there's nothing under the link you provided, only: No Product Found in this criteria

Comment: https://www.telemart.pk/mobile-and-tablets/mobile-phone.html

Comment: take a look again i modified it

Comment: Oh, it's dynamically downloaded by the website... you won't get it using `requests`. Try using `Selenium`, with which you can get the website after some dynami content is loaded. Check e.g. here: https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-using-selenium-python-8a60f4cf40ab

Comment: but if you see in inspect and then go to network tab and then xhr then you can see "0" and all data present in that

Comment: yes, it's there! but `request` make only a `GET` call for static `html` content. if you want to download the files from `XHR` tab, you should use either `Selenium` or `JavaScript`+`ajax`, which are designed for supporting dynamic content.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the content from that page using post http requests like the way I've shown below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.telemart.pk/index.php/home/listed/click/{}'

payload = {
    'category': '35',
    'rating': '',
    'sub_category': '',
    'brand': '',
    'attributesids': '',
    'ishiddenprice': '0',
    'featured': '',
    'range': '6499;471999',
    'express_delivery': '',
    'text': '',
    'view_type': 'grid'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link)
    csrf_id = r.cookies['csrf_cookie_name']
    payload['csrf_test_name'] = csrf_id

    for i in range(0,144,48):
        res = s.post(link.format(i),data=payload,headers={"x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
        for item in soup.select(".product-details"):
            product_name = item.select_one("h2.product-name").get_text(strip=True)
            price = item.select_one(".price > ins").get_text(strip=True)
            print(product_name,price)
```

Comment: what if i want to get list from all 3 pages ?

Comment: The above script is already parsing content from all three pages. You didn't actually go through the answer, right?

Comment: but let if there are 5 pages then?

Comment: This is the logic `5*48+1` to create the highest range. There are other ways, as in you can parse the highest paginated number and multiply with 48. However, don't ask multidimensional question in one go. The question you asked in the first place has already been answered. If you have further questions, make sure to create a new post. Thanks.